# Description of DIF file format as used by Excel?

Tags: excel, file-format

What is the layout of a DIF file, and, more importantly, what is the meaning of the different header and data fields in one? The Wikipedia article has enough information that I suspect this would be an easy-to-generate format that's richer than CSV. But I can't find a good enough description of this format to actually generate it.

Answer (score 1):

When I have such issue, I usually go at Wotsit, here at the [Spreadsheet / Database Files](http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?fc=6) section, and see if they have anything.

They have a Dif.zip file with a DIF.txt file inside which is a short (164 lines) description of the format.
I cannot guarantee the description is official/complete, but it might be a good start.